# Size differences between TrueType and OpenType fonts when using PIL ImageFont

Tags: python, image, fonts, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create PNGs of letters from the fonts on my system. Seems to work okay with TrueType fonts (.ttf) but not OpenType (.otf). The images formed are the same size but the actual letters appear much smaller with OpenType - see below.

I'm using the ImageFont module from the Python Imaging library. There doesn't seem to be a way to distinguish between the two formats; both are imported with

```
ImageFont.truetype(filename, size)
```

What am I missing?

---

example code:

```
try:
 font = ImageFont.truetype(name, size)
 for text in string.letters:

  size2 = font.getsize(text)
  
  im = Image.new('RGBA', size2, (0, 0, 0, 0))
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
  draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill="black")
  
  if not os.path.exists(name[:-4]):
   os.makedirs(name[:-4])
  
  if text in string.lowercase:
   im.save(name[:-4]+".png")
  else:
   im.save(name[:-4]+"_u.png")
except:
 pass
```

---

[image: small b]
[image: big b]

Images of Adobe Caslon and Arial for comparsion.

Comment: Can you tell which size you gave for the two fonts in question?

Comment: I used 72 as the size variable.

Comment: Can you post some example code?  And what does font.getsize() return?   (from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965466/imagefonts-getsize-does-not-get-correct-text-size)

Comment: font.getsize() returns the tuple I would expect. It is only used for calculating the canvas size which appears to be correct - in the example I gave, you can see how the canvas for the Adobe Caslon 'B' is a similar size to the Arial, but it is the letter itself which is too small. I've updated my question with some example code.

Comment: This is old, but could you retry on PIL 1.1.7 ? It works fine for me.