# Python PILLOW created text is in wrong position

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on the python script to create enter data to pre-created image.
For this I'm using Python's PILlon and I'm developing on Windows 7.

I am struggling with function draw.text(), in which I enter position to be (0,0). Unfortunately, text is positioned a bunch of pixels down.

Firstly, I thought it was my mistake, I search the web and found the page http://tools.jedutils.com/tools/center-text-image, where the code for (centered, but problem is the same) image is that:

```
def create_image(font_name, font_size, font_color, width, height, back_ground_color, text, image_filter=None):

font  =  ImageFont.truetype ( font_path + font_name + ".ttf", font_size )

im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
text_x, text_y = font.getsize(text)
x = (width - text_x)/2
y = (height - text_y)/2
draw.text ( (x,y), text, font=font, fill=font_color )

#if filter: #i don't need given filter
#    real_filter = filter_dict[image_filter]
#    im = im.filter(real_filter)
im.save ( "runaway_emboss.jpg" )
```

After executing this code, I encouraged the same problem as I had with my own script. Later I thought it may be problem of font, so I copied one from Windows Fonts folder to my *.py file location, I tried downloading fonts from the web. Everything had the same result.

Image of the problem:

Bad: [image: Bad]
Good: [image: Good]

Do you have any idea, what might be the source of the problem?

Comment: Probably a dupe of [ImageFont's getsize() does not get correct text size?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1965466). This is a font problem, not something Pillow is doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageFont's getsize() does not get correct text size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965466/imagefonts-getsize-does-not-get-correct-text-size)