# PIL's ImageFont.getsize() gives wrong text size

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, truetype

I am using this code to get width of text :

```
from PIL import ImageFont

fontPath = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ANTQUAI.TTF"
fontSize = 80
text = "Flabbergasted Monkey Inc"

font = ImageFont.truetype(fontPath, fontSize)
sz = font.getsize(text)

>> sz
(853, 96)
```

After inspecting the drawing, it seems that the width is 940.

So I created this .html file which shows that the width is actually 940, not 853 :

**File flab.html**

```
<svg width='940' height='400'><rect x='0' y='0' width='940' height='400' stroke='red' stroke- 
width='2px' fill='rgba(124, 240, 10, 0.5)' fill-opacity='0.0'/>
<text x='0' y='200'  style="font-family:'Book Antiqua'; font-size:80px; font-weight:normal; font- 
style:normal; stroke-width:3; fill:rgb(178, 143, 221); text-anchor:start; dominant- 
baseline:alphabetic; " >Flabbergasted Monkey Inc</text>
</svg>
```

Is this a bug or ...I'm missing something ?

Oh by the way. This happens with other fonts too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImageFont's getsize() does not get correct text size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965466/imagefonts-getsize-does-not-get-correct-text-size)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thanks for link, it does have some useful info. Not a good solution though. I want to display text with a simple SVG file, so to draw on a canvas, then crop, just to get text size... sounds like overkill.